# Change ng-if statement in app.js from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, angular-ng-if

I want to change my `ng-if` value "loggedIn" in index.html from my `login/login.js` by using this codes

```
$scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Logging in as ', $scope.loginData.email);
  AuthService.login($scope.loginData)
    .then(function() {
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        $scope.layout = 'styles';
        $state.go('app.mainReg');

        $stateParams.id = $currentUserId;
        console.log($currentUserId);
    });
};
```

and I have this kind of stateProvider in my app.js

```
.state('app', {
            url:'/',
            abstract: true,
            views:{
                'bodyLogin': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/login/body.html',
                    controller  : 'BodyController'
                },
                'bodyMain': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/main/body.html',
                    controller  : 'BodyController'
                }
            }
        })
.state('app.mainUnreg', {
            url:'home',
            views: {
                'content@app': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/login/home.html',
                    controller  : ''
                }
            }
        })
.state('app.mainReg', {
            url:':userID',
            views: {
                'header@app': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/main/header.html',
                    controller  : ''
                },
                'sidebar@app': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/main/sidebar.html',
                    controller  : ''
                },
                'middle@app': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/main/home.html',
                    controller  : ''
                },
                'footer@app': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/main/footer.html',
                    controller  : ''
                }
            },
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
```

and I separate each state by div

```
<div ng-if="!loggedIn" ui-view="bodyLogin" class="site-wrapper" ui-sref-active="app.mainUnreg"></div>

<div ng-if="loggedIn" ui-view="bodyMain" ui-sref-active="app.mainReg"></div>
```

but, I seems that it didn't give any effect, even I have logged in and being redirected, the statement for `loggedIn` didn't change, still `false`

I have put the files in [GitHub](https://github.com/edenlyriene/speak_out/)

Does anyone have any idea where I made some mistake, so my loggedIn statement couldn't be changed?

Comment: make sure you're not shadowing the rootScope variable with a controller scope variable with the same name

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I just realized that I always call "$scope.loggedIn = false" inside my controller, so it didn't work. Thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

Just change `<div ng-if="!loggedIn"` to `<div ng-if="!$root.loggedIn"`

Comment: Thank you, Roman. I just realized that I always call `$scope.loggedIn = false` inside my controller, so it didn't work. Thank you!